# Font awesome icon inline with table border css/bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have added a font awesome icon in a table by using the following code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<table class="table table-bordered w-auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column_1</th>
      <th>Column_2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="form-group">
        <input type="Column_1" class="form-control" id="clmn1" placeholder="Enter the name">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a class="fa fa-plus-circle" href="#"></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to bring this icon to the bottom line and center of that column, i.e. one half of this icon is inside and the other half is outside the table.

Comment: where is your css? what have you tried

Comment: I tried in bootstrap

Comment: What's your bootstrap version? Can you create a code snippet, so we can edit it?

Comment: I created a quick codepen for you. https://www.codeply.com/p/K617Z3ygIw

Comment: Apply a negative margin-top, use relative positioning, or transform:translate …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by setting the containing div to `position: relative` and define for the icon `position: absolute` and `top: 0.375rem`, the half of the `padding` of the containing div (`0.75rem`).

```css
.form-group div {
  position: relative
}

a.fa-plus-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.375rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<table class="table table-bordered w-auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column_1</th>
      <th>Column_2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="form-group">
        <input type="Column_1" class="form-control" id="clmn1" placeholder="Enter the name">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a class="fa fa-plus-circle" href="#"></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```